# C# file not showing after export after deploying in Docker Container

Tags: c#, docker, containers

I've written a tiny application to fetch few rows from database and put them in the flat file and export to a path provided in the config (eg. c:\exportfiles)

The application works totally fine while running in local.

I'm deploying the application the Docker Container - The application runs successfully, it also logs (console.writeline) as the file is created, the length, path and name of the file, but when I look into the folder I find nothing.

I think the path needs to be mapped using Volumes - I'm not sure how to do it. What path should I give in the config to export the files? How do I map it in the docker volumes?

My application needs to save the export file while running in container as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount the volume. In your docker run statement, add a flag for volumes as follows:

```
docker run {Your container creation info} -v "{Your host path to folder}":"{Your container path to folder}"
```

This should mount the volume, meaning the directory in your container will be shared with the directory on your host machine.
The paths are up to you as to where you want them to go.

Comment: Isn't possible to mount the volume while 'create' container? I'm getting error -- Error response from daemon: pull access denied for cont02, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

Comment: I was able to fix the above issue, I ran below statement but didn't work. The file is not getting exported to the location (c:\akb\deploy)

 docker run --name subcont subimg -v c:\akb\deploy:C:\ProgramData\Docker\volumes\subscriberfiles\_data

Comment: The application result shows as file is exported to "c:\akb\deploy" location, but nothing is exported there. It works fine while running the c# application in local.

Comment: When you say "nothing is exported there" it looks to me like you are pointing your volumes in different places and expecting them to match. You're probably going to need to do a bit more reading on volumes and experiment some to get a full understanding of them.

Comment: You're right, I misplaced the location of both. When I swapped, it worked! I need to learn more about it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to [mount a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to your Docker container.

In simple words - volume is a location on your host file system which is accessible from the Docker container as well. If you are using Dockerfile to pack your application, check out [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).